# Enable to send mails with Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm using `Swiftmailer` with `Symfony 2.8` to send mails from a gmail account to an outlook account.
The code I'm using in my controller:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Test Email')
    ->setFrom('xxxxx@xxxxx.com')
    ->setTo('xxxxxx@outlook.com')
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(

            'QualifBundle:Mails:Welcome.html.twig'
            ),
        'text/html'
    );
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Configuration file:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    encryption: %mailer_encryption%
    auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_username%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

Parameters yml:

```
mailer_username: xxxxxxx@gmail.com
mailer_password: xxxxxxxxx
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
```

I managed to solve SSL errors, now with this code my app runs without exceptions but the mail is not received ( maybe not even been send )
How can I solve or fingerprint this ?

**Update**
I removed `spool:{ type: memory }` so that mails get send directly and I got this exception.

```
Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [Connection refused #111]
```

My Host is supposed to be `smtp.gmail.com` not the `localhost` any idea ?

**Solution**
I solved my problem by hacking into vendor's files, I know it's not the best solution but at least I can send mails.

look for `_establishSocketConnection()` fonction in `StreamBuffer.php` should be in this path `/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport` into the project.
And add those following lines to escape SSL verification:

```
//...
$options = array();
if (!empty($this->_params['sourceIp'])) {
    $options['socket']['bindto'] = $this->_params['sourceIp'].':0';
}
//Add those two lines
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
//...
```

Then I restarted the browser I mailing works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I solved my problem by hacking into vendor's files, I know it's not the best solution but at least I can send mails.

look for `_establishSocketConnection()` fonction in `StreamBuffer.php` should be in this path `/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport` into the project.
And add those following lines to escape SSL verification:

```
//...
$options = array();
if (!empty($this->_params['sourceIp'])) {
    $options['socket']['bindto'] = $this->_params['sourceIp'].':0';
}
//Add those two lines
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
//...
```

Then I restarted the browser I mailing works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your gmail account thatYou have to turn on ["Access for less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in your gmail account

Comment: Turned it on .. same result

Answer (score 0):

Another way around:

```
$opt['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
$opt['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;

$this->get('swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real')->setStreamOptions($opt);
```

code above to be placed before: `\Swift_Message::newInstance()`